# Java - Factory class that creates an abstract object?

Tags: java, constructor, static, factory, abstract

I have the 2 following abstract classes:

```
public abstract class AbstractCarChecker implements CarService {

}
```

and the below which extends AbstractCarChecker

```
public abstract class CarChecker<T extends Car> extends AbstractCarChecker {

}
```

I want to have a factory class that will instantiate a CarChecker object, so that all subclasses (e.g. `FordCheckerFactory`) can extend it to create instances.

```
public class CarCheckerFactory {

    public CarCheckerFactory() { }

    public static CarChecker newFrom(String carName, String carReg) {

        CarChecker carChecker = new CarChecker(carName, carReg);

        return carChecker;
    }

}
```

However the issue is that I cannot instantiate `CarChecker` as its abstract.

What is the best approach to this, use an `if statement` to decide what concrete implementation to return? e.g. pass "ford" into the `newFrom` method to know to create a FordChecker object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
public static CarChecker newFrom(String carName, String carReg, String className) {
    Class<?> theClass = Class.forName(className);
    Constructor<?> cons = theClass.getConstructor(String.class,String.class);
    CarChecker carChecker = cons.newInstance(new Object[] {carName, carReg });
    return carChecker;
}
```

where `className` pertains the name of the concrete class.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create instances of abstract classes (and as a consequence, 'abstract object' just isn't a thing).

The whole notion of factories is that they represent the notion of creating things. Therefore, the `newFrom` method should NOT be static (because then it might as well have been a constructor and the factory as a concept is useless; factories serve the function of having constructors that can have polymorphic behaviour, just like instance methods can). Thus:

```
public interface CarCheckerFactory<T extends Car> {
    CarChecker<T> newFrom(String carName, String carReg);
}

public class FordCheckerFactory implements CarCheckerFactory<Ford> {
    return new FordChecker(carName, carReg);
}
```